# How to set difference sources for a Target based on OS platform in swift package manager?

Tags: swift, cross-platform, swift-package-manager

I'm using swift package manager to build a project for 2 platforms, linux and windows.

In my project, I have some cross platform sources and some other platform specific sources.

My question is, how to set different sources for the target by platform?

```swift
.target(
    name: "MyTool",
    dependencies: ["Utility"],
    sources:[],           //<----------------platform specific
    linkerSettings: [
        .linkLibrary("openssl", .when(platforms: [.linux])),
    ]
),
```

what I want is something like `.when(platforms: [.linux])`, but it's for `sources`, how can I do it?
If it's not possible in `sources`, `target` level is also acceptable.

Comment: What's wrong with using something like `#if os(linux)`?

Comment: Or, create separate targets for the platform-specific code, and have the common code depend on them conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Sweeper for his suggestion, I never thought I can use standard swift code in `Package.swift`.

Then my solution is like this:

```swift
let sharedSource:[String] = [

]
let windowsSource: [String] = [

    ]

var targetSource :[String]
#if os(Linux)
    // Code specific to Linux
    print("Running on Linux")
#else
    // Code for other platforms (not Linux)
    targetSource = sharedSource + windowsSource
#endif
```

then

```swift
        .target(name: "StCorelib",
            sources:targetSource,
```

Very nice!